# Android on/off view

Tags: android, view

How can I have an on/off selector like the one the one shown in ICS's WiFi or bluetooth settings? [Example](http://www.zdnet.co.uk/i/z5/illo/nw/story_graphics/11dec/ice-cream-sandwich/android-ics-2.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Hope can help to you: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b12d5a9b3e5c236f?pli=1

Comment: The question linked explains only how to turn Wi-Fi on and off, not how to have an on/off selector, as stated in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want to imitate from standard Android applications download the source code and copy+paste.

Comment: where can I find the soure code of the settings application ?